# which way is better for my login form to be outside my angular material sidenav

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular8

in my app i have material sidenav component and all others component are inside this sidenav  like the exemple below :

```
    <!-- this is inside my app.component.ts -->
    <app-side-nav *ngIf="loggedIn">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </app-side-nav>
```

the problem is that i want my login Form component to be outside the sidenav so i come with two approach:

- this is the first one :

```
    <!-- also in my app.component.ts
     use variable loggedIn to see if the user is logged in or not -->

    <div *ngIf="!loggedIn" class="login-app">
        <app-authentication></app-authentication>
    </div>
    <!-- if the user loggedIN -->
    <app-side-nav *ngIf="loggedIn">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </app-side-nav>
```

- this is the second one

```
    <div *ngIf="!loggedIn" class="login-app">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
    <!-- if the user loggedIN -->
    <app-side-nav *ngIf="loggedIn">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </app-side-nav>
```

in the second one i used routing for login form and also used Guard for the other components 
**my question are:**

1. what is the best approach ??
2. is there a better way to do this in a secure manner ??

> PS: the two approaches work just fine !!

Comment: Have a look at Angular Guards and implement an Auth Guard that protects certain routes. That way, the user can attempt to navigate to a certain route, then your guard can check if they are allowed or not and handle that appropriately, either by redirecting to a safe page or giving them an unauthorised message. A note on security. You're giving code to your client (user). This can never handle your security needs as they could just change the code and hit whatever page (if they really wanted to). Real authentication must be validated server side. Hope this helps

Comment: thanks  james for the clarifications
In facts i use guard in the second approach and this is just a front-end in the back-end we work with spring security framework